# python requests - detection

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to know if i can be detected before the request is sent back from the server. and if i can be stopped from getting the results.

I mean i know that its very easy to insert a javascript code that checks if the mouse is moving or a key is pressed, but i am wondering if the http request sent from python is able to pass something like that.

I don't think so, right?

So the main question is:

Can i be stopped from getting back the result?

I am using cookies, user agent and so on.. ..but no key presses and etc because the requests module.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to receive response from server, I think you should configure this on server side or you can send a `http request` to server with a fake source IP address but this could not be accomplished by `requests` module.

Recommend `scapy` module for you.  http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

Comment: It has proxy support. I want to know if the response can be stopped from the server/site. Thank you, i was reading scapy doc while you were typing :P

Comment: @user215379 Who has proxy support?

Comment: Python requests module has proxy support.